# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type when emulating addEventListener

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In a class instance method I'm trying to implement a behaviour similar to `EventTarget.addEventListener()`. A simplified version with a function is in [this TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgsAUALgngDgUwAQFEBuCB2UCCSC8SA3kpgIYC2CAXEgM5QBOAlpgOYDcSAvh5LIlQZsAIQLEkUZlVqYArhQBGCRl16QQwSKEisoKgGZkAxsnRZcE8jPpNWnHnwh7DJs8KhiSUm-KUq1J01tcAhgiGMAGzI6OiELPAQAD31MABM482wJODlFSOZjJEYEMjSAe0xImFJKGlsWdnEAcma1SCiYzI8xZNSM+OySXPzC4tKKqpqfer9lRnEABnaIXWxXU0GoAFkyOGJIJCRmhA8AWjJm2izcJyOT88UrrZEnbkhIAzlMYylKpDKaRuABlmAwsCoADwAaSQfSwAwA1ggYOUDFtdnAAHwACkOkng9WhABokAVwZgVLQcacLNcPJiANrQgC6AEoCFikGhysw0pAOUR8ZEEFA4R4cPSEuJ5JFIgC4mRMDA7mTReKLCIpaIZXI5QqAcqnPi6AB3ZhQYwACyQOIECEF+KOxhiyAeFguVydRzJYNSKhpErZqp9SEUJTIiONEFDLrobtp2DOT2o3qO5P9jEDmuDabDEaj+PeEGLQA). Copying it here anyway:

```
class EventA extends Event { public readonly name: string = ''; }
class EventB extends Event { public readonly time: number = 0; }

interface EventMap {
  'event-a': EventA;
  'event-b': EventB;
}

function addEventListener<K extends keyof EventMap>(
  type: K, listener: (event: EventMap[K]) => void
) {
  // emulate behaviour when event should be notified to listener

  let eventA: EventA = null as any; // generated somewhere
  let eventB: EventB = null as any;

  switch (type) {
    case 'event-a':
      listener(eventA); // <-- error here
      break;

    case 'event-b':
      listener(eventB); // <-- error here
      break;
  }
}
```

When I'm in a switch case, the type is known and hence the input listener type is known. So I'd assume I could invoke the listener with an event of matching type. But instead I got error for A (and equivalent for B):

```
Argument of type 'EventA' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventMap[K]'.
  Type 'EventA' is not assignable to type 'EventA & EventB'.
    Property 'time' is missing in type 'EventA' but required in type 'EventB'.
```

How should the function change so that I can safely invoke a listener with an event of matching type? I mean, without using casting to `any` or similar.

For clarity's sake, in real solution I'm *not* invoking listener right when it's added. TA

Comment: I think this is one of the places where a type assertion is necessary. `EventMap[K]` resolves to `EventA & EventB` rather than one or the other depending on the value of `K`. You have to tell the compiler you know better than it does by writing `listener(eventA as EventMap[K])` and `listener(eventB as EventMap[K])`.

Comment: In fact the event type resolves to `EventA & EventB`. I don't understand really why. Anyway, you might want to put that as an answer.

Comment: It's because the generic constraint is `K extends keyof EventMap`. Your intention is that `K` be either `"event-a"` or `"event-b"`, but `"event-a" | "event-b"` also extends `keyof EventMap`, which means `EventMap[K]` must include the value of both keys.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict that generic type, or using another generic type, so that it's not `... extends keyof EventMap`, but instead is `... exactly only keyof EventMap`, so to speak?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I think you need to use the type assertion. But I could be wrong, maybe someone else knows a way!